# What is wrong with my conditional?

Tags: solidity

I seem to have trouble finding good resources demonstrating how to set up conditionals with the correct syntax.  I thought I had it right, but this code does not work.  I used other examples of conditionals as a guide and am not sure what I missed here.

```
function changeTruckStatus(address _address) onlyMember public {
    if (truckowners[truckAddrIndex[_address]].active == true) {
        truckowners[truckAddrIndex[_address]].active == false;
    } else {
       (truckowners[truckAddrIndex[_address]].active == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the ideal form for a question. Could you look at the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It helps keep the community clean and helps new users. :) . More context would help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is you are mixing up the conditional equals `==` and the assignment equals `=`.

Your code should read:

```
function changeTruckStatus(address _address) onlyMember public {
    if (truckowners[truckAddrIndex[_address]].active == true) {
        truckowners[truckAddrIndex[_address]].active = false;
    } else {
       truckowners[truckAddrIndex[_address]].active = true;
    }
}
```

Where you are *assigning* the boolean value after the conditional statement.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I see I also only need the parentheses around the if statement.

Comment: It seems to me that you might be new to programming in general (based on these errors). My suggestion is that while Solidity and Ethereum are exciting, the documentation and projects you can tackle are still too sparse for a new programmer. I suggest instead you look at JavaScript and Python as your entry into developing code, and then transition to Solidity once you are more familiar.